# ASP.NET MVC - Como realizar o upload de um arquivo com mais de 5mb usando ajax?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc

Estou utilizando o seguinte código para realizar upload de arquivos:

HTML:

```
<form action="/Employee/FileUpload?UnityId=1&amp;ObjectId=1" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-failure="OnFailure" data-ajax-method="Post" data-ajax-success="OnSuccess" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form6" method="post" class="MultiFile-intercepted"><div class="card default">
    <input multiple type="file" tabindex="-1" name="File" required title=" " autocomplete="off" maxlength="10" onchange="this.setCustomValidity('')" data-maxsize="10240" class="multi custom-file-input" accept=".bmp,.jpeg,.jpg,.pdf,.xls,.xlsx,.csv,.txt,.mp4,.mkv,.avi,.wmv,.mp3,.3gp,.doc,.docx">
    <input id="file" name="submit" role="button" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary validate-form upload-archive" tabindex="0" value="Enviar" />
</form>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(function () {
$("#form6").submit(function (event) {
    var dataString;
    event.preventDefault();
    var action = $("#form6").attr("action");
    if ($("#form6").attr("enctype") == "multipart/form-data") {

        dataString = new FormData($("#form6").get(0));
        contentType = false;
        processData = false;
    } else {

    }
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: action,
        data: dataString,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: contentType,
        processData: processData,
        success: function (data) {

        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

            alert("fail");
        }
    });
});
```

});

CONTROLLER:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult FileUpload(string ObjectId, string UnityId, HttpPostedFileBase File)
    {
         .. Meu código
    }
```

Com esse código estou conseguindo fazer upload de arquivos de até 5mb, no entanto quando tento carregar um de 9mb o código não funciona, o controller sequer é chamado e não é exibida nenhuma mensagem de erro.

Existe algum limite para o upload de arquivos usando esse método?

Como posso fazer para resolver esse problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essa limitação é do asp, para alterar é só mudar a parametrização no seu arquivo web.config, exemplo:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="xxx" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Perfeito. Era exatamente isso.